# bind gridview using linq

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

i try to populate data in grid view using linq ..
i try this

```
private void populateveh()
    {
        TData1 tg = new TData1();
        GridView1.DataSource = tg.select_regionveh();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }.

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.populateveh();
    }
```

but this shows error

```
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

in this line
 GridView1.DataSource = tg.select_regionveh();

method

```
   #region Function Imports

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public int select_regionveh()
    {
        return base.ExecuteFunction("select_regionveh");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

any solution?

Comment: What is the return type of `select_regionveh()` method?

Comment: select_regionveh is store procedure

Comment: Can you show us the method definition for `select_regionveh()`?

Comment: check update please

Comment: That's the problem, this method returns an `int` but expected data should be either of these types `IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource`

Comment: Check the definition of `ExecuteFunction` by pressing `F12` on method.

Comment: @user6408005 DataSource must be a type of collection as the exception is stating ( It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource)

Comment: when i check quick watch by click on execution .. this show ..   ExecuteFunction 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: so what is the solution

Comment: @user6408005 So you want to add only 1 row to the `GridView`??

Comment: no.. there is multiple rows..

Comment: @user6408005 Your `select_regionveh` method returning an `int`. How are you expecting multiple rows??

Comment: but when  i create procedure and update model automatically in visual studio then this shows return method int.. i can not create this method

Comment: helllooooo? any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't say so, I assume your object GridView1 is a DataGridView. According to [MSDN DataGridView.DataSourceProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) must implement one of the following four interfaces:

- The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
- The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
- The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList class.
- The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

This means that the DataSource property can only be used to show a sequence of items, not just one item.

You want to show the return value of TData1.select_regionveh(). This return value is not a sequence, it is only a single integer.

Perhaps you want to populate your DataGridView with only this single integer?

In that case there are two possible methods:

**DataGridViewRowCollection**

If you have defined columns for your DataGridView, you can add single items as follows:

```
int addedRowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewRow addedRow = Gridview1.Rows[addedRowIndex];
addedRow.Cells[columnValue.Index] = tg.select_regionveh();
addedRow.Cells[columnDescription.Index] = ... // other columns
```

**BindingList method**

You can create a bindinglist of type T where T is the type you want in your rows. Add your returned integer to this list:

```
BindingList<MyType> bindingList = new BindingList<MyType>();
MyType x = new MyType()
{
    myProperty1 = tg.select_regionveh(),
    myotherproperty = ...,
}
bindingList.Add(x);
GridView1.DataSource = bindingList;
```

The advantage of using a typed bindingList is that you don't have to populate cells one by one when writing or reading values to and from the datagridview. You just read and write them to the BindingList.

The disadvantage is that the operator has less freedom while editing the cells of the DataGridview. For instance, if your BindingList shows a DateTime property, then the display value must always be in a format that can be parsed to a DateTime. The user can't say: "For now I'll only fill the year. I fill the rest of field later before I press OK"

Comment: but when i create procedure and update model automatically in visual studio then this shows return method int.. i can not create this method

Comment: But what value do you want to show? the returned int? or are there other out-parameters that form a collection of items that you want to show?